# function nested in if statement

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, location, match

I'm having an issue with the following code if anyone could help me I'd be most grateful. Basically I have several links on several pages on a page that call urls. At the moment it's only calling the function within the `/freeten/` part of the code even if the extraten page is open in the window.

```
if(location.href.match('/extraten/')) {

    console.log(window.location.href);

    function downloadXM() {
        if(location.href.match('/en/')) {
            window.location.href = "http://core77.com/";
        }

        if(location.href.match('/fr/')) {
            window.location.href = "http://www.notcot.org/";
        }

        if(location.href.match('/de/')) {
            window.location.href = "http://www.spd.org/";
        }

        if(location.href.match('/it/')) {
            window.location.href = "http://sxsw.com/";
        }

    }
}

if(location.href.match('/freeten/')) {

    function downloadXM() {

        if(location.href.match('/en/')) {
            window.location.href = "http://www.wired.com/";
        }

        if(location.href.match('/fr/')) {
            window.location.href = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/";
        }

        if(location.href.match('/de/')) {
            window.location.href = "http://edition.cnn.com/";
        }

        if(location.href.match('/it/')) {
            window.location.href = "http://www.sky.com/";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Move the ifs inside one function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of declaring functions that way, try doing this:

```
var myFunc;

if (something) {
    myFunc = function () { ... }
} else if (something) {
    myFunc = function () { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest change is this.
Not elegant but extensible for noobs

```
function downloadXM()  {
  window.console && console.log(window.location.href); // helping IE 

  if (location.href.match('/extraten/')){     

    if (location.href.match('/en/')){    
      window.location.href= "http://core77.com/";
    }

    if (location.href.match('/fr/')) {  
      window.location.href= "http://www.notcot.org/";
    }

    if (location.href.match('/de/')) { 
      window.location.href= "http://www.spd.org/";
    }

    if (location.href.match('/it/')) { 
       window.location.href= "http://sxsw.com/";
    }    
  }

 else if (location.href.match('/freeten/')){     

    if (location.href.match('/en/')){    
        window.location.href= "http://www.wired.com/";
    }

    if (location.href.match('/fr/')) {  
        window.location.href= "http://www.bbc.co.uk/";
    }

    if (location.href.match('/de/')) { 
        window.location.href= "http://edition.cnn.com/";
    }

    if (location.href.match('/it/')) { 
        window.location.href= "http://www.sky.com/";
    }
}
```

Comment: Just remember that `window.console` might exist, but `console.log` may not `:)`

Comment: Never had that. Mine will at least stop ie from failing when the console is closed

Comment: Of course it will, and it's good you're thinking about it. The perfect solution though would be `window.console && typeof window.console.log === "function"`. Just a tiny suggestion!

Comment: What browsers have a console that does not have a log function? I think I would only encounter your issue if someone created var console = ...

Comment: Let me reply with a question: is it possible to have a variable called `console` in the global scope?

Comment: As I guessed. Yes it is, and too bad if you do ;)

Comment: That's true. In old versions of ECMAScript you could even define `undefined`, but that's a topic for a separate conversation :)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript hoists the function declaration to the top of the function so your first declaration of `downloadXM()` gets overwritten by the second `downloadXM()`. Javascript does not have any block scopes like the one you are trying to do with the if statements.

Comment: Block scope is not really relevant for this question. With block scope it would completely break because the functions wouldn't be available outside the `if` bodies at all.

Comment: I think I did say that javascript doesn't have any block scopes. So your point??

Comment: He is not trying to create a block scope but simply did not know about the hoisting mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

One other item, you are using `.match(<RegExp>)`, which actually returns an array of all matches in the string for the RegExp patterns that you are using.  In this case, what you probably want to use is `<RegExp>.test()`, which returns either `true` or `false` for whether or not the RegExp pattern is matched in the string value.

Using an example of this from your code:

```
if (location.href.match('/extraten/')) {
```

. . . would become:

```
if (/extraten/.test(location.href.match)) {
```

**Edit** - I am not saying that this is what was causing your issue, but I got inconsistent results as I was testing your code using the `match()`.  Switching it to use `test()` resolved those issues.

Comment: But `.match()` will still evaluate as "truthy" if the array is not empty (and "falsy" otherwise)

Comment: True, but when I tested his code, it was giving inconsistent results.  Using `.test()` resolved them. If you are looking for a `true` or `false` answer, best to ask a `true` or `false` question.   ;)